# A series $\sum a_n$ converges if $a_n$ is a nonnegative sequence satisfying $a_{n+2}<\frac{a_{n}+a_{n+1}}{n+2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a nonnegative sequence satisfying $a_{n+2}<\cfrac{a_{n}+a_{n+1}}{n+2}$. How can we show that the series $\sum a_n$ converges? It seems that if we use the recursive inequality repeatedly, then we may obtain an inequality of the form $a_n< f(n) (a_1+a_2)$.. But I cannot find a pattern. Any hints?

Comment: If we only had $a_{n+2} < a_{n+1} / (n+2)$, are you able to show that the series converges?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes then we would have $a_n<c/n!$ for some constant $c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set for all $n$, $b_n = \max\{a_{2n},a_{2n + 1}\}$. Then, for all $n$,
$$
a_{2n + 2} \leqslant \frac{a_{2n} + a_{2n + 1}}{2n + 2} \leqslant \frac{2b_n}{2n + 2} = \frac{b_n}{n + 1},
$$
and if $n$ is large enough, $\frac{n + 2}{(n + 1)(2n + 3)} \leqslant \frac{1}{n + 1}$ thus,
$$
a_{2n + 3} \leqslant \frac{a_{2n + 1} + a_{2n + 2}}{2n + 3} \leqslant \frac{b_n + b_n/(n + 1)}{2n + 3} = \frac{(n + 2)b_n}{(n + 1)(2n + 3)} \leqslant \frac{b_n}{n + 1}.
$$
We deduce that for $n \geqslant N$ large enough, $b_{n + 1} \leqslant \frac{b_n}{n + 1}$ so $b_n \leqslant \frac{N!b_N}{n!}$ In particular, the series of the $b_n$ converges, so does the series of the $a_n$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $\frac{n + 2}{(n + 1)(2n + 3)} \leqslant \frac{1}{n + 1}$ holds for all nonnegative integers $n$.

Comment: Yes, probably, it was easyer to justify like this, but I don't think it is hard to show that it holds for all $n \geqslant 0$.